problemas al cargar un archivo jar
estoy trabajando en un proyecto en spring boot, y al construir se genera mi archivo jar. Resulta que cuando ejecuto el comando "jar tf build/libs/inventario-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" me sale una excepcion de que la clase no ha sido encontrada. y cuando voy a mirar mi manifest.mf esta asi

Main-Class: com.caciquesport.inventario.inventario.InventarioApplication Start-Class: com.caciquesport.inventario.inventario.InventarioApplicatio n Spring-Boot-Version: 3.1.10 Spring-Boot-Classes: BOOT-INF/classes/ Spring-Boot-Lib: BOOT-INF/lib/ Spring-Boot-Classpath-Index: BOOT-INF/classpath.idx Spring-Boot-Layers-Index: BOOT-INF/layers.idx Build-Jdk-Spec: 17 Implementation-Title: inventario Implementation-Version: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

y esta es la forma en la que configuro el manifest desde buil.gradlew
tasks.named('bootJar') {

manifest {
    attributes(
        "Manifest-Version":"1.0",
        "Main-Class":  "com.caciquesport.inventario.inventario.InventarioApplication",
        "Start-Class":"com.caciquesport.inventario.inventario.InventarioApplication"
    )
}

}
desde mi ignorancia, creo que el problema esta en el salto de linea que se hace en la ultima n de la parte de  "Start-Class" en el manifest.

y esta es la ruta mi clase main


Ya encontre lo que me ocurria, en el buil.gradlew tenia tambien esto :
`

springBoot {
mainClass = 'com.caciquesport.inventario.inventario.InventarioApplication'
}

`
el inicializar el nombre del mainClass en springboot y tambien en bootjar, causaba conflictos, elimine el bootjar y funciono perfecto
